# Crystal report designer for visual studio 2010 on windows 10 is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, windows-10

I have windows 10 recent installed, when i install crystal report for visual studio 2010 CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9 my app is working but the designer in visual studio 2010 is not working.
The report designer is working fine in windows 7.

Comment: Try to use 32bit  CRRuntime.

Answer (score 0):

You need the install executable to be able to design reports, not the redistribution. Link to the SAP page: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports,+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Comment: I download the Support Pack 19, the problem is solved, thanks,